# Allow mouse event behind a plotband

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I need to display a plotband at the bottom of a column/area chart.
I achieve that by coloring it with a transparent gradient, allowing to see chart content :

```
color: {
linearGradient: { x1: 0, x2: 0, y1: 0, y2: 1 },
stops: [
[0, 'rgba(255,255,255,0)'],
[0.94, 'rgba(255,255,255,0)'],
[0.95, '#ff0000'],
[1, '#ff0000']
]}
```

The result must be displayed like that : http://jsfiddle.net/f98a2vo9/. You can see that the plotband must be at the front of the chart content.

But, I also need to allow tooltip to be displayed... and I didn't see at all how to achieve this with this plotband solution.

Maybe with an event propagation displayed series, or somthing like that ?

Thanks by advance for your help.

Comment: Why must it be in front of the chart points? A plot band is supposed to show the data point in context of some event. Showing a plot band above a point is more like showing the event in the context of a data point set. While interesting it would maybe be better to use a different series type instead of a plotBand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using a different series. You set this one to be at the height/span you want but do not show in legend. You can also remove from tooltip (I leave that to you):

```
series: [{
  data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 100.0, 100.0, 100, 100.5, 100.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
}, {
  type: 'area',
  marker: {
    enabled: false
  },
  point: {
    events: {
      mouseOver: function() {
        return false;
      }
    }
  },
  events: {
    mouseOver: function() {
      return false;
    },
    mouseOut: function() {
      return false;
    }
  },
  color: '#ff0000',
  showInLegend: false,
  data: [{
    x: 2.5,
    y: 25
  }, {
    x: 4.5,
    y: 25
  }]
}]
```

Example [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/w576247u/).